# STM32 USB Full Speed device: Do you need termination resistors?

Tags: stm32, usb-device

I'm designing a board based on the STM32F103C8T6.  ST has a [guide for USB hardware design](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/application_note/group0/0b/10/63/76/87/7a/47/4b/DM00296349/files/DM00296349.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00296349.pdf) for ST32 microcontrollers that explicitly states you should not use any external resistors.  "In peripheral mode, the VBUS power is always provided through the cable. **The USB FS impedance driver is always managed internally to avoid the need to add external serial resistors on the data line path.**"

The guide also has about a half dozen diagrams that show a direct connection of DP and DM between the USB port and the MCU with no resistors in series:

[image: no termination resistors on DP and DM]

However, every real-world design that I can find based on this MCU puts 22 ohm termination resistors in series with DP and DM.  The most prominent example is the open source Blue Pill development board, which is based on the exact same MCU.  Here's a portion of its schematic:

[image: blue pill schematic with 22 ohm termination resistors]

Another example using 22 ohm termination resistors that is based on a similar STM32 is [here](https://stm32world.com/wiki/Magic_Key).

So, should I add 22 ohm series termination resistors to the DP and DM lines or not?  ST's guide is emphatic that this is not necessary, and yet the Blue Pill is a working device that is in commercial production, which is strong empirical evidence that the resistors are, at a minimum, not hurting anything, and maybe are necessary.

(I also wonder what would be the consequence of including these resistors even if they are in fact unnecessary as ST claims?  It won't change the differential impedance of the two lines, but it will (I think) cause increased reflections on the lines and thus slow down the data transfer rate.)

Answer (score 6):

You should believe the manufacturer and manufacturer examples.

Many other designs simply copy over a previous design with different MCU which may have different recommendations. Sometimes the recommendations differ even between different MCUs in the same family.

And judging by looking at the schematic you provided, the Blue Pill even got the USB pull-up resistor value wrong, so there is no reason to trust the rest of it either.

A lot of hobbyists don't read manuals in detail and they get the schematics wrong. Unfortunately the Internet is full of incorrect schematics that just get copied around, because apparently very few actually read data sheets, reference manuals, application notes, and reference designs themselves.

Regarding the resistors, since they are not needed because correct termination and driving circuitry is already provided by the chip, it will change the differential termination, as you are adding 44 ohms to what is supposed to be 90 that already exists inside the chip, and it will needlessly slow down signal edges, so longer cables may not work. It won't slow down communications itself, but if data gets corrupted there may be retransmissions needed, or link has so many errors that the device is disconnected and maybe reconncted automatically. The point is that if it does not fit to USB requirements for a compliant USB device, then it's not an USB device.

Comment: Thanks.  I think you are probably right about this.  By the way, I also noticed that the Blue Pill is using the wrong DP pullup resistor, and the full schematic has some other "mistakes" (in my opinion anyway).  The only reason I put some stock in it is that its a thing out there in the world that is being sold and is known to work.  However, it may have unreliable USB and it sells anyway because most of the people buying it are not bothered or affected by that.

Comment: @jemalloc Based on questions here, I mostly just know it from the problems it has, not how it is known to work. And there may be several different clones; I've seen worse problems too, in just the small part of the schematics you posted.

Comment: Can you explain to me why adding the two 22 ohm resistors would change the differential impedance?  I understand why it would change the single ended impedance of each line, but if identical 22 ohm resistors are added symmetrically, shouldn't they cancel each other out?  Here is a discussion of calculating the odd mode impedance for a pair of microstrip lines:  https://www.signalintegrityjournal.com/blogs/12-fundamentals/post/1665-what-is-differential-impedance-and-why-do-we-care.  It's entirely a function of the self and mutual inductance and capacitance of the lines. What am I missing?